# Bokeh:: RuntimeError: PhantomJS is not present in PATH or BOKEH_PHANTOMJS_PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, path, bokeh

I am trying to export a Bokeh plot to png using their `export_png` method from `bokeh.io`, however, I am running into an RuntimeError, stating PhantomJS is not present in PATH or BOKEH_PHANTOMJS_PATH.
I am using the Jupyter notebook environment with Python 3.7.3.

I've tried `conda install -c conda-forge phantomjs` and `conda install -c conda-forge selenium` (as well as `conda install phantomjs` and `conda install selenium`), but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated - I am happy to provide more detail!
Here is a segment of the exception below:

```
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/io/webdriver.py in create_phantomjs_webdriver()
     73                                     '("conda install -c bokeh selenium" or "pip install selenium")')
     74 
---> 75         phantomjs_path = detect_phantomjs()
     76         return webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path, service_log_path=devnull)
     77 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/util/dependencies.py in detect_phantomjs(version)
    124     except OSError:
    125         raise RuntimeError('PhantomJS is not present in PATH or BOKEH_PHANTOMJS_PATH. Try "conda install phantomjs" or \
--> 126             "npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt"')
    127 
    128     return phantomjs_path

RuntimeError: PhantomJS is not present in PATH or BOKEH_PHANTOMJS_PATH. Try "conda install phantomjs" or "npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt"
```

Comment: Did you conda install phantomjs in to the same conda environment that the notebook is running from?

Comment: Yes, this worked - I will post a quick workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I figured out a way to handle this issue...

FIRST: try this:
`conda install -c conda-forge phantomjs`

If that doesn't work, then do the following:

I verified that I had the `phantomjs` library in my anaconda3 environment (as below).
`/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/phantomjs`

The issue is, my Jupyter notebook was working in a environment that was not anaconda3.
So what I did is:

1) `conda install nb_conda_kernels`
2) Close the anaconda application altogether
3) Open anaconda, and under the "Applications on __________" (upper left dropdown menu in the anaconda main menu view), I selected "anaconda3"
4) Open Jupyter Lab (perhaps Jupyter notebook will also work)
5) Re-executed my code and WALA! it worked.

Let me know if you guys have any questions.